# How to get average value (of column values) of a category (distributed in rows)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, pivot-table, worksheet-function

I have data in Excel in the format:

```
Type:   Price:
A       10
A       20
D       30
A       50
D       60
```

How can I get average price of each category (A, D)?

To be clear:
[image]

Data given in figure is just example for simplicity. Actually I have 13000 rows with that kind of data with 99 categories distributed in rows and given a 'Price' in second column.

Comment: have a look at `AVERAGEIF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a PivotTable.

Based on your data sample:

[image: SO34192183 example]

Comment: Thanks that is easier than Marco' solution because I do not have to extract unique values manually.

Comment: Pnuts I need help again. How to count amount of occurences of each category without having to create unique values manually. I was trying to find how to do it using Pivots  but just could not find.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in E3 and drag down till E6:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A$3:A$16,D3,B$3:B$16)
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is the formula for averaging in excel. Just change and/or add cells as desired and enter it all into the cell you want it to display in.

=AVERAGE(A2:A6)